# React native edit list with button

Tags: react-native

Hi i'm new in react native here's my code. I can list data in flatlist comes from api

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  FlatList,
  Image,TextInput
} from 'react-native';   

export default class Example extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      dataSource: [], 

    };
  }    
  renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems:'center', height: "auto",width:'auto', borderRadius: 8, borderColor: 'white', backgroundColor: "cyan", margin: 3, marginBottos: 3 }} >
        <Text      > {item.text} </Text> 
      </View>
    )
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const url = "https://.herokuapp.com/getList";
    fetch(url).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          dataSource: responseJson.data.dict,
          limit: responseJson.data.itemLimit
        })    
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (

      <View style={{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
      }}>
        <View  >
          <Text >  Header</Text>

        </View>

        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Now its like left side. I gotta put a button thats easy then onpress it gotta open modal or another page with list of inputs. List item limit is 20 so we can create list inputs with 20 item but gotta fill it with data.

[image]

I gotta make inputlist with data comes from api,same as it .May I make it with foreach or is there some real solution

Thank you i can open any idea

Answer (score 0):

No you don't want to foreach for every item simply warp your render item as follows

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={}>
 <View style={{ 
     flex: 1, 
     alignItems:'center', 
     height: "auto",width:'auto',
     borderRadius: 8, 
     borderColor: 'white', 
     backgroundColor: "cyan", 
     margin: 3, 
     marginBottos: 3 
    }} >
        <Text> {item.text} </Text> 
 </View>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

in TouchabaleOpacity onPress method call a function to navigate to your next screens with parametrs(items do you want to send next screen).Then next screen you can access those values. For that refer below link,

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/

Comment: Well i may open new screen but how to show list of inputlist,

Comment: You have to implement TextInputs as you need then you have pass params you get from pervious screen and set to "value" prop in TextInput